# Using AsyncTask in SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: android, android-widget

To improve the performace of my `ListView` I implemented an `AsyncTask` to handle some operations on a `Cursor`. Here's the code.

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        holder.desc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.desc);
        holder.status = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.status);
        holder.path = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.path);
        holder.icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        holder.position = position;
        convertView.setTag(holder);
        Log.d(Tag.getTag(this), "convertView is null");
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    class CursorTask extends AsyncTask<ViewHolder, Void, String[]> {
        private ViewHolder v;
        private String vdstatus, mbpath, vsname, vsdesc, vsstatus, vspath;
        String iconid;
        @Override
        protected String[] doInBackground(ViewHolder... params) {
            v = params[0];
            Cursor mCursor = getCursor();
            mCursor.moveToPosition(position);
            String[] mArray = new String[] { mCursor.getString(1),
                    mCursor.getString(2), mCursor.getString(5),
                    mCursor.getString(7), mCursor.getString(6),
                    sdpath + propmanager.mbActivePath(),
                    mCursor.getString(4) };
            return mArray;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String[] mArray) {
            super.onPostExecute(mArray);
            vsname = mArray[0];
            vsdesc = mArray[1];
            vsstatus = mArray[2];
            vspath = mArray[3];
            vdstatus = mArray[4];
            mbpath = mArray[5];
            iconid = mArray[6];
            if (v.position == position) {
                v.name.setText(vsname);
                v.desc.setText(vsdesc);
                v.status.setText(vsstatus);
                v.path.setText(vspath);
                switch (Integer.parseInt(iconid)) {
                case 0: {
                    v.icon.setImageDrawable(drawable_a2s);
                    break;
                }
                .................
                .................
                .................
                case 17: {
                    v.icon.setImageDrawable(drawable_cid);
                    break;
                }
                }
                if (vdstatus == "false") {
                    v.status.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                } else {
                    v.status.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#4B8A08"));
                }
                if (mbpath.equals(vspath)) {
                    v.name.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    new CursorTask().execute(holder);
    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    ImageView icon;
    TextView name, desc, status, path;
    int position;
}
```

The problem with this is that in some `position`s [towards the end and top(shows correctly at first, but wrong after scrolling) of the `ListView`] the data is displayed wrong. Also I have 8 `ListView` `child`s but the maximum value of `position` I'm getting is 4. Why is this happening? How can I fix this?

Comment: why are you using an async task on this? You're spawning a thread for every single item in your listview which is terribly inefficient and, in your case, completely pointless. You aren't gaining anything by using an async task and, in this case, you're actually slowing your listview down a whole lot. Additionally, if you remove your async task you won't have the problem you're having. Async task is meant for long running tasks.. mapping a string to a textview from a cursor is a fairly instantaneous task and can be left on the main thread.

Comment: @dymmeh My `ListView` was initially jerky but now scrolling smooth after adding this. Probably got to do with working on drawables, The `AsyncTask` not only maps string but calls `Runtime.exec()` ( i mean `propmanager.mbActivePath()`) etc, but that's not shown here. Its the

Comment: what is mbActivePath() actually doing? Also curious why you're using actual drawables instead of just pointing to a resource drawable. Maybe you're loading them from a website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really inefficient and resource consuming. You should really use `AsyncTask` once in you application to load your `ListView` data into memory, and then keep it there and use to fill your `ListView` items. Solution for your problem is **caching** instead of **loading in background**.